# How do I use a PHP class in my rails 3.1+ application?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, api, class

I need to use the MultiSafePay.com gateway in my Rails 3.1 application. They don't have ready-to-go code snippets for rails, but they do have a PHP class with all functionality.

[PHP Class ZIP file](http://www.multisafepay.com/downloads/msp_php.zip)

The class itself is 700 lines with numerous api methods, so re-writing it in ruby will be a pain.

Is it possible to use the PHP class in my Rails application?

If not, is there anyone who can recommend a gem with MultiSafePay support?

Comment: If that class provides a REST interface, you could make simple HTTP requests to it from *almost* any language and receive data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like: https://github.com/tenderlove/phuby

Example(As per their Github page):

```
rt = Phuby::Runtime.new
rt.start

rt.eval('$hello = "world"')
assert_equal "world", rt['hello']

rt.stop
```

I'm not sure how the paths will work when including the MultiSafePay class, but it's worth a try.